# Can not set environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS

Tags: c, ubuntu, environment-variables, openmp

Maybe it is stupid question, but how I can set *OMP_NUM_THREADS* in my ubuntu shell?
I can't see any OMP variable and I can't set any...

[image: The problem]

Comment: export OMP_NUM_THREADS=12